# Get selected ListView item number (in which line it is)

Tags: c#, listview

I imported a text file into a `ListView`.

If an item in `listView1` gets selected, it's `Linenumber` should be stored in an `int`.

For example (this is a `ListView` (text file)):

```
Candy (1)
Coffe (2)
Sugar (3)
```

If a line is selected for example `Sugar`, the `Linenumber` (3) should be stored in an int.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is this a WinForms project, WPF project, or an asp forms project? because they all have a `ListView` control.

Comment: it's a WinForms project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get the value like that:

```cs
int myIndex = myListView.Items.IndexOf(myListView.SelectedItems[0]);
```

I did not test the code.

Comment: You would just do `myListView.Items[0]` rather than this more convoluted method to get a specific index, but that isn't what's being asked in the question.

Comment: i dont't think that myListview.Items[0] and what i have written is the same as myListView.SelectedItems seems to be an array of Elemets that have been selected... and myListView.Selecteditems[0] would return the first one

Comment: You're right, it's not quite the same, but why would you get the selected item and search for it in the Items collection when you can just do `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: You ar right it can be achieved easier by the following: int myint = myList.SelectedIndex();

Comment: I got an error with: int myint = myList.SelectedIndex(); because it's a Listview not a Listbox

Comment: Does yourList.FocusedItem.Index help?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index of the selected item in a ListView via the [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. You may need to add 1 to it because they are zero-indexed.